# Visual Studio 2015 in C++ does not support C99

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c99

When I try to compile by C++ compiler some code with designated initializers (C99).
And obviously I have errors due to it.

Does somebody know how to enable support of C99 for C++ code ?

Comment: did you try "extern "C" { ... } "

Comment: Change the extension to .c and it will use C-syntax. However, you didn't post any output or errors whatsoever, so I'm only guessing.

Comment: @Goodies: I have such macros:
#define String_init(value) { .next=NULL, value, .obj=NULL }
And I need compile code exactly by C++ compiler cause I have customer objects with overloaded operator.

Comment: @Eric Abramov: It does not work for macros )

Comment: Which do you want? C++ or C99? You can't them both.

Comment: Post an [mcve] that demonstrates what you want to do. Obviously it won't build, but odds are much better than someone can point you in the direction of a work-around with a sample to work from.

Comment: You asked much the same question 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756468/how-to-compile-a-mixed-file-c-and-c-with-c-compiler

Comment: Me and others already told you they are different languages and you likely will have more than just `void *` issues. You can't have them both in the same compilation unit.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried the following:
Created a new C++ Win32 Console application, **without** Precompiled header, changed the source file extension to .c, and wrote this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int a[6] = { [1] = 1 };

int main()
{

    printf("a[1]=%d\n", a[1]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It worked for me. Output was as expected.

UPD:
The answer is for the case your purpose is to compile a C code in Visual Studio,  not if you are trying to use C features in C++ code.

Comment: That does not answer the question. OP wants to use C language in C++. Juch the same like mixing Java and C++ or Python and Ruby in the same source code. C++ and C are different languages.

Comment: I am not sure your comment is accurate and comparisons are good.
C code is supported in C++.
As well, OP wants to use C code in Visual C++ 2015 IDE as I understand, which doesn't necessary mean that he wants to use C++.

Comment: It's funny you announce what I think and what I do not think about these languages.
I think your rubby/python comparison are not in place - you are taking it too far.
What would you say about "extern "C" " technique that is allowed in C++ and so on.
Of course they are different languages, but most of C code (because of same syntax) will work in C++.
From the question it is not clear whether the author has an issue with Visual C++ or with C++ language itself.

Comment: You might want to meditate what "Even identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. " means! For instance try `const i = 10; static int a[i];` in both languages! And use markdown in comments as well address comments properly.